# Google Drive e-mail from HTML form using a php handler

Tags: php, html, email, google-drive-api

I have created a folder on my Google drive and put my css/html/php/images..etc files on there.
When I point my browser to www.googledrive.com/host/x, where x is the folder ID, I get the index.html page.

What I am trying to do is to have a form on that page that sends an e-mail to my gmail account.

This is the form I'm using:

```
<title>Form submission</title>
    <form action="mail_handler.php" method="post">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        Message:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I also created a mail_handler.php file I saw on another post here with the following in it:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $to = "myemail@gmail.com"; 
        $from = $_POST['email']; 
        $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
        $subject = "Form submission";
        $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
        $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
        $message2 = "Here is a copy of your message " . $first_name . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
        $headers = "From:" . $from;
        $headers2 = "From:" . $to;
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
        mail($from,$subject2,$message2,$headers2);
        echo "Mail Sent. Thank you " . $first_name . ", we will contact you shortly.";
    }
?>
```

So that should send two e-mails, one to me and one to the sender with a copy of the message.

When I fill the form and hit 'Submit' I get an error from Google:

"405. That’s an error.

The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know"

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Google drive doesn't support PHP - you'll need to host this somewhere that has PHP support. As a side note, Error 405 means 'Method Not Allowed' i.e. it doesn't support the POST method.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. Do you have any suggestions for free decent webhosting?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query=mysql_query(select * from table_name)
$table="";

$table .="<table border='1'  style='background-color:#C0C0C0;' >
    <tr>
     <th bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>Agent Name</th>
     <th bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>Count of  VOICE - Agent Name</th>
     <th bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>Average of Total Time</th>
     </tr>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

          $table .="<tr>";
          $table .= "<td>" . $row['agent_name'] . "</td>";
          $table .= "<td>" . $row['name_count'] . "</td>";
          $table .= "<td>" . $row['total_aht'] . "</td>";
      }
       $table .="</tr>";
         $table .= "<tr><td bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>Total</td><td bgcolor='#E6E6FA'>$y</td>
$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject="hii";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From:<abc@gmail.com>" . "\r\n";
$mail=mail($to,$subject, $table,$headers);
    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but you can you add some context as to what this does?? The code is pretty ambiguous.